# In AppleScript or JavaScript how can you click menu item?

Tags: applescript, javascript, alfred, javascript-automation

I need to change a theme using a script for Mojave, Alfred and Sourcetree. I've already successfully done this with Mojave and Alfred using this script:

```
var alfredLightTheme = "Alfred"
var alfredDarkTheme = "Alfred Dark"

function run(args) {
    args = args ? args : []
    var systemEvents = Application("System Events")
    var alfred = Application("Alfred 3")

    if (args && args == 'dark') {
        systemEvents.appearancePreferences.darkMode = true
        alfred.setTheme(alfredDarkTheme)
    } else if (args && args == 'light') {
        systemEvents.appearancePreferences.darkMode = false
        alfred.setTheme(alfredLightTheme)
    } else {
        systemEvents.appearancePreferences.darkMode = !systemEvents.appearancePreferences.darkMode()
        alfred.setTheme(systemEvents.appearancePreferences.darkMode() ? alfredDarkTheme : alfredLightTheme)
    }

}
```

For Sourcetree it seems I need to click the menu items but how can I do that?

[image: sourcetree change theme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP is tagged with both **AppleScript** and **JavaScript**, and are two entirely separate languages, and it was not explicitly and specifically stated that the solution had to be only in **JavaScript**, here it some *code* that should work. I say "should work", because it does work on the applications tested on, but I do not have **Sourcetree** installed to test explicitly and specifically with it.

**AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "Sourcetree" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    click menu item ¬
        "Dark" of menu 1 of menu item ¬
        "Theme" of menu 1 of menu bar item ¬
        "View" of menu bar 1 of application process "Sourcetree"
end tell
```

<sup>**Note:** The *value* of the `delay` *command* may need to be adjusted for your system.</sup>

---

**JavaScript** *code*:

```
menuItemClick("Sourcetree", ['View', 'Theme', 'Dark'])

function menuItemClick(strAppName, lstMenuPath) {
    var oApp = Application(strAppName),
        lngChain = lstMenuPath.length,
        blnResult = false;

    if (lngChain > 1) {

        var appSE = Application("System Events"),
            lstApps = appSE.processes.where({
                name: strAppName
            }),
            procApp = lstApps.length ? lstApps[0] : null;

        if (procApp) {
            oApp.activate();
            var strMenu = lstMenuPath[0],
                fnMenu = procApp.menuBars[0].menus.byName(strMenu),
                lngLast = lngChain - 1;

            for (var i = 1; i < lngLast; i++) {
                strMenu = lstMenuPath[i];
                fnMenu = fnMenu.menuItems[strMenu].menus[strMenu];
            }


            fnMenu.menuItems[
                lstMenuPath[lngLast]
            ].click();
            blnResult = true;
        }
    }
    return blnResult;
}
```

**Note:** The **JavaScript** *code* comes from [jxaClickAppSubMenuItem.applescript](https://gist.github.com/bumaociyuan/a37c78cd5503f371b391) by bumaociyuan and was [forked from RobTrew/jxaClickAppSubMenuItem.applescript](https://gist.github.com/RobTrew/575111796d0e3bf9bf3a).